# Why are there so few "running" processes?

Tags: process, top, scheduling

On all of BSD/Linux/MacOS and Solaris, I made an observation - no matter how busy the system is, `top` always reports very few (usually 1-2) running processes.

According to my limited understanding, a process is in "running" state if it is using CPU time, or waiting for CPU time to become available.

So, here is a scenario: I use SSH to tunnel VNC, then run `top` on remote machine, in a Terminal emulator:

- `top` itself is listed as a "running" process (understandable)
- `sshd` is listed, but not "running"
- `Xvnc` is listed, but not "running"

But `sshd` is tunneling VNC traffic, `Xvnc` is what keeps me updated with screen content, how can they not be using CPU time?

If they are using CPU time, then how come they are not "running"?

Comment: Different OS, slightly different angle, exact same thing: [Task Manager is saying the system is running with over a thousand threads](http://superuser.com/a/615824/53590) on SuperUser. (Full disclosure - link points to my, accepted, answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is a question of timing. `top` checks CPU state every N seconds. At the moment the check is run, `top` will *have* to be active since it is actively checking the state of the system. A nice way of seing this in action is to decrease the update time of `top` and watch your processes move! As suggested in `man top`:

```
   o  The  user  interface,  through  prompts and help, intentionally
      implies that the delay interval is limited to tenths of a  sec‐
      ond.   However,  you're  free to set any desired delay.  If you
      want to see Linux at his scheduling best, try a  delay  of  .09
      seconds or less.

      For this experiment, under x-windows open an xterm and maximize
      it.  Then do the following:
        . provide a scheduling boost and tiny delay via:
            nice -n -10 top -d.09
        . keep sorted column highlighting Off so as to
          minimize path length
        . turn On reverse row highlighting for emphasis
        . try various sort columns (TIME/MEM work well),
          and normal or reverse sorts to bring the most
          active processes into view

      What you'll see is a very busy Linux  doing  what  he's  always
      done  for you, but there was no program available to illustrate
      this.
```

If you try this, you should see more processes going into `R` mode. You can also try running `top` in batch mode a few times and collecting the processes that are marked as running:

```
sudo nice -n -10 top -d.09 -bn 100 | awk '$8~/R/{print $NF}' | sort -u
```

On my system under its current load (which includes an open ssh tunnel) I get the following processes:

```
cinnamon
firefox
kworker/0:1
kworker/1:2
kworker/2:2
kworker/3:0
plugin-containe
ssh
tint2
top
Xorg
```

Answer (score 4):

Most processes are waiting for something to happen, a packet coming from the network, a disk I/O to complete, a human typing on its keyboard or exercising its mouse these days, with such fast CPUs being the norm.

Launch a compute intensive process, like some picture or movie processing and it will show up as running.

Of course, `top`, while analyzing the processes will always find itself running for obvious reasons.

Note that the status displayed is not an average value but a snapshot so even processes much busier than `top` might always be shown a sleeping for sampling reasons.

Comment: Thanks. What does `top` do to classify itself as a running process all the time? My system has many other processes which use much more CPU time than `top`.

Comment: Answer updated.